# How do I do a selection from table and a mapping using one of the column from the table as key?

Tags: sql, dictionary, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Given the table `main`:

| abc | pqr | price | lang |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hello | hallo | 2.34 | en_de |
| world | welt | 1.23 | en_de |
| coffee | cafe | 9.23 | en_fr |

And a map that looks like:

```
with mappings AS (
    SELECT MAP (
        ARRAY['en_fr', 'en_de'],
        ARRAY['1', '2']
    ) AS lang2idx
)
```

The goal is to extract a table where the output

| abc | pqr | lang | index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hello | hallo | en_de | 2 |
| world | welt | en_de | 2 |
| coffee | cafe | en_fr | 1 |

I've tried this which fetches the index id I need from the mapping:

```
with mappings AS (
    SELECT MAP (
        ARRAY['en_fr', 'en_de'],
        ARRAY['1', '2']
    ) AS lang2idx
)
SELECT lang2idx['en_fr'] FROM mappings
```

I tried to do **some selection from different tables, it kind of goes haywire**, it throws a syntax error:

```
SELECT abc, pqr, lang, (lang2idx[lang] FROM MAPPINGS) FROM main
```

**How do I do a selection from table and a mapping to produce the desired output like above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would go with "simple" CTE and join. Something along these lines:

```sql
with mappings (lang, index) AS (
    values ('en_fr', '1'),
           ('en_de', '2')
)

SELECT m.abc, 
  m.pqr, 
  m.lang, 
  mm.index
FROM main m
LEFT JOIN mappings mm on mm.lang = m.lang
```

If you want to keep the original CTE as is, you can use [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
WITH mappings AS (
  SELECT MAP (
    ARRAY['en_fr', 'en_de'],
    ARRAY['1', '2']
  ) AS lang2idx
),
unnested as (
   SELECT t.*
   FROM mappings,
   unnest (lang2idx) as t(lang, index)
)

SELECT  m.abc, 
  m.pqr, 
  m.lang, 
  mm.index
FROM main m
LEFT JOIN unnested mm on mm.lang = m.lang
```

And another option, closest to your attempt (assumes only one row in the `mappings`) - join with selection by key:

```sql
SELECT abc, 
  pqr, 
  lang, 
  element_at(mm.lang2idx, m.lang) index
FROM main m
JOIN mappings mm on true -- or cross join mappings mm
```

Comment: Is it `unnested mm as (` instead of `unnested as (` ?

Comment: @alvas not following you. `unnested as (` specifies another CTE with name `unnested` and `unnested mm` is using `unnested` in the join assigning it an alias `mm`.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, I thought `unnested` was a keyword. Understood the solution now =)

Comment: @alvas added one more option.

Comment: Thank you! The last option is great for unique keys in the mappings!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
WITH mappings AS (
  SELECT MAP (
    ARRAY['en_fr', 'en_de'],
    ARRAY['1', '2']
  ) AS lang2idx
),
indexed_main AS (
  SELECT 
    abc, 
    pqr, 
    lang, 
    lang2idx[lang] AS index
  FROM 
    main 
    JOIN mappings ON mappings.lang2idx.keys[array_position(mappings.lang2idx.keys, main.lang)] = main.lang
)
SELECT 
  abc, 
  pqr, 
  lang, 
  index
FROM 
  indexed_main;
```